# Web-Scraping Amazon products

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape multiple Amazon product pages. If I print the title, for instance, it does not print the title for both links or ASINs, but only for the latter one. How can I print the title of both ASINs?

```py
ASIN = ['B09C1Q9P1N','B096W87PPJ']
for a in ASIN:
    url = 'https://www.amazon.de/dp/' + a + '/'
driver.get(url)

urls = 'https://www.amazon.de/dp/B09C1Q9P1N/','https://www.amazon.de/dp/B096W87PPJ/'

soupa = soup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
title = soupa.find(id='productTitle').text.replace('\n', '').replace('  ', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but I gather you are using selenium? Have you tried putting it into a for loop for each URL such as:

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver

# Your webdriver code here

urls = ["https://www.amazon.de/dp/B09C1Q9P1N",
    "https://www.amazon.de/dp/B096W87PPJ"]

for url in urls:
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

    for title in soup.find_all("span", {"id": "productTitle"}):
        print(title)
```